# Storing input into Arrays in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm just got into Visual Basic and I'm trying to "recode" my programs from java into VB. But my main problem is how to do that, i don't the syntax too much. I have read some but I find it hard(I'm a slow learner :P).

Edit:
Here is the code I am trying:

```
Module Module1
Dim arrays(5) As String

Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your Names:")
    For i As Integer = 0 To arrays.Length
        arrays(i) = Console.ReadLine
    Next i

    For Each arr As String In arrays
        Console.WriteLine(arr)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

End Module

At some point, whenever I run it and try to input, it goes beyond the number of index. And doesn't write the inputs :P

Comment: Please share some code and you need to be more descriptive to get some help.

Comment: So some effort, also show what Java are you trying to translate to VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a zero based array, you need to get the length - 1. Your array is set to 5, so it has 6 elements and arrays. Length = 6 where your loop needs to be 0 to 5.

```
Module Module1
Dim arrays(5) As String

 Sub Main()
  Console.WriteLine("Enter your Names:")
  For i As Integer = 0 To arrays.Length - 1
    arrays(i) = Console.ReadLine
  Next i

  For Each arr As String In arrays
    Console.WriteLine(arr)
  Next
  Console.ReadLine()
 End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you :)